# Prevent request to another domain?

Tags: javascript, cors, xmlhttprequest, xss, content-security-policy

I want to administratively prevent a whole class of XSS attacks by not allowing anything on my page to send XHR/XMLHttpRequest (or other?) requests **to** other domains than the domain hosting the page. Is that possible?

I thought I could do that with [Cross-Origin Resource Sharing (CORS)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS), but it seems I was wrong. If a page hosted on domain-a.com tries to make an XHR request to domain-b.com, CORS can be used *on domain-b.com* pages to control whether or not that is allowed.

So if something on the page at domain-a.com tries to make an XHR request to hackers-r-us.com that will be allowed, as long as hackers-r-us.com sets the appropriate CORS headers.

But is there anything I can set on the page on domain-a.com to disallow requests to other domains such as hackers-r-us.com regardless of CORS headers on hackers-r-us.com?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

To prevent requests to another domain, use [CSP](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Security-Policy) — specifically, the [`connect-src`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Security-Policy/connect-src) CSP directive.

CSP directives are specified using the `Content-Security-Policy` HTTP header, and enforced by browsers. The simplest example of a header that specifies a `connect-src` directive is:

```
Content-Security-Policy: connect-src 'self';
```

If you serve a document at `https://example.com/foo/` with that, browsers block any  frontend code in the document from making requests to URLs at any origin other than its own (`'self'`); i.e., browsers  restrict the allowed requests only to URLs starting with `https://example.com`.

- https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Security-Policy/connect-src has more details and examples.
- https://w3c.github.io/webappsec-csp/#directive-connect-src is the actual spec section where the browser requirements are defined; that section also has some examples.